# Ubuntu USB installation does not boot on a Dell Inspirion N5010

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB Hard Drive (WD Elements, 1TB) from my desktop PC.
The boot loader is installed on the USB HD, too, and it boots with no problems from that PC.

I've tested it on a VAIO notebook, it boots from it, too.

But on my Dell Inspirion N5010 I got big troubles. I only get a black screen when trying to boot from it.

I also tried a Bootmanager CD called "Plop Bootmanager", it get the error "no valid bootsector signature" when trying to boot from the HD.

Well, the USB HD seems at least to be supported by the BIOS, because when I override the MBR using "testdisk",
I get a console prompt with "1234F".

Well, what could be the problem why the HD fails to boot on the Dell notebook?